# Do the STL concepts cover all of the argument requirements for STL algorithms?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, c++-concepts, callable-object

When looking at the template names of some of the algorithms,
I see that the name corresponds to a library concept.

Take [std::mismatch](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch) for example.

```
template< class InputIt1, class InputIt2, class BinaryPredicate >
std::pair<InputIt1,InputIt2>
mismatch( InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
          InputIt2 first2,
          BinaryPredicate p);
```

It takes a `BinaryPredicate` which is also a [library concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BinaryPredicate).

---

Looking at other algorithms though, I see:

- UnaryPredicate
- UnaryFunction
- UnaryOperation
- BinaryOperation
- etc

and they have no corresponding concept.

Is there a reason they have been left out?
Are these concepts derivable by combining existing concepts?

Comment: cppreference documented some of them and not others. I think you are overthinking it.

Comment: `UnaryPredicate` seems like a synonym for `Predicate`, at the very least.

Comment: `BinaryPredicate` is a term/type name that's used and defined in the actual C++ standard (see section 25.1, paragraph 9 of [this draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf)). However, the terms `UnaryPredicate` and `UnaryFunction` never occur in the standard. `BinaryOperation ` and `UnaryOperation` are used in the standard but aren't defined nearly as explicitly as `BinaryPredicate`.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ Standard doesn't define "concepts". It defines "requirementes" like:

```
EqualityComparable, LessThanComparable, DefaultConstructible,
MoveConstructible, CopyConstructible, MoveAssignable, CopyAssignable,
Destructible, NullablePointer, Hash, TrivialClock, Allocator,
Swappable or Container
```

But some requirements use different syntax than the others. For example, `allocator` and `swappable` use lowercase italics (*allocator*), and the others from my sample list a camelcase monospace font, or, as described in the standard, constant with type (**`EqualityComparable`**).

Other "concepts", as `PODType`, are treated in the standard as just definitions.

For example, `BinaryPredicate` isn't defined as concept nor definition; just as a template name of the functions using it:

```
void unique();
template <class BinaryPredicate> void unique(BinaryPredicate pred);
```

> *Effects*: Erases all but the first element from every consecutive group of equal elements referred to
>   by the iterator `i` in the range `[first + 1,last)` for which `*i == *(i-1)` (for the version with no
>   arguments) or `pred(*i, *(i - 1))` (for the version with a predicate argument) holds. Invalidates
>   only the iterators and references to the erased elements.
>
> *Throws*: Nothing unless an exception is thrown by the equality comparison or the predicate.
>
> Complexity: If the range `[first,last)` is not empty, exactly `(last - first) - 1` applications of
>   the corresponding predicate, otherwise no applications of the predicate.

As you see, the `BinaryPredicate` isn't defined. It just shows how it affects the behaviour of `std::unique`.

In the other hand, the [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept) concept list is extracted from the *concept* proposal, which is non-standard. Besides, `cppreference` isn't perfect, and not every wiki page is complete or full described from the point of view of the concept proposal, and there are other template parameters that don't even appear in the standard, like `UnaryOperator`.

Comment: Cppreference list on that page has "named requirements used in the normative text of the C++ standard", not the ones from the concept (actually ranges) proposal.